# Why is assigning a listener to process.stdout "error" event produce a memory leak?

Tags: node.js, jestjs, memory-leaks

As the title says, Jest is recognizing the following pattern as a memory leak:

```js
export const createNodeWriter = () => {
  process.stdout.on('error', () => {});

  return () => {};
};
```

Here is a [PR#81](https://github.com/gajus/roarr/pull/81) that replicates this issue.

```bash
$ npm run test:jest

> roarr@1.0.0 test:jest
> jest --detectLeaks

 FAIL  jestTest/memoryLeak.test.ts
  ● Test suite failed to run

    EXPERIMENTAL FEATURE!
    Your test suite is leaking memory. Please ensure all references are cleaned.

    There is a number of things that can leak memory:
      - Async operations that have not finished (e.g. fs.readFile).
      - Timers not properly mocked (e.g. setInterval, setTimeout).
      - Keeping references to the global scope.

      at onResult (node_modules/@jest/core/build/TestScheduler.js:150:18)
      at node_modules/@jest/core/build/TestScheduler.js:254:19
          at Array.map (<anonymous>)

Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
Tests:       0 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        0.942 s, estimated 1 s
Ran all test suites.
```

I am not clear what is about this code that makes it a memory leak.

I thought maybe it is called multiple times, but that isn't the case... or at least adding a guard for it does not make the Jest error go away.

```js
let bound = false;

export const createNodeWriter = () => {
  if (!bound) {
    bound = true;
    process.stdout.on('error', () => {});
  }

  return () => {};
};
```

Comment: I suspect this is a bug in Jest memory leak detection https://github.com/jestjs/jest/issues/14580

Comment: Perhaps jest is just complaining about an event listener left on stdout when you finish?  Other than that (which is not a leak in any way), there's nothing wrong with this code so perhaps it just a false positive.

Comment: FYI, `return () => {};` inside of `createNodeWriter()`  is odd.  Is there a real reason for that?  If you are saving that return value when calling `createNodeWriter()`, then node may be unable to garbage collect the scope inside of `createNodeWriter()`.  Or, perhaps the GC is smart enough to see that the function is empty, I don't know.